# Iptables rule to block http traffic not working

Tags: ubuntu, iptables

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --destination-port 80 -j DROP
```

Seems that this rule is not blocking the internet traffic comming from the subnetwork (10.0.0.*)

Blocking ssh and ftp works well..

**Iptables**

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ftp
2    DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
3    DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
2    ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
```

Comment: Please share `iptables-save` output.

Comment: Try blocking ports 443 and 8080 in addition to 80.

Comment: Please show the output of "iptables -L -v" instead. Thanks.

Comment: No fix for this ? I have the same pb... I block my IP on all ports. I do get banned on SSH but port 80 is still accessible whatever I do. This is making me nuts.

Comment: What traffic do you want to block? Traffic directed at your machine or traffic going through your machine?

Answer (score 1):

please chek that ipv6 is disabled. there is ip6tables. ipv6 firewall rules need to be set separately.

try to disable ipv6 and see if then the iptables rules apply:
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1